# Passing props through react router not available in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router

I've passed props via the react router like this to the mentioned component:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/product-page" exact render={(props) => ( <ShopPages {...props} response={this.state.response}/>)}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

I would like to access this props in `componentDidMount()` like something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
 console.log(this.props.response)
}
```

The prop `this.props.response` is available in the component I can console.log it in the render(). I'm not sure why in the above scenario the  console shows the array empty. I've tried to see if the data is available then show the data as so `console.log( 'show', this.props.response && this.props.response)` or by adding `async` as so:

```
async componentDidMount() {
const data = await this.props.response
}
```

But this does nothing too. Any help?

Comment: remove `()` of around your `<shopPage ... >` component that you rendering it , see if it changes ????

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to assume that `this.state.response` is not a Promise, but is actually the data since you said it was an empty array, therefore async/await will do nothing.

ComponentDidMount() is only fired once when the component mounts and is NOT the place to perform actions based on prop updates that can happen after mount. So I would suggest passing the promise, and if that is not an option do something like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (!prevProps.response.length && this.props.response.length) {
      //Your code
    }
  }
```